# Как в WordPress вызвать PHP-функцию при нажатии на кнопку?

Tags: wordpress

Есть форма (в Админ-панели!):

```
<textarea id="my_ta">Lorem ipsum!</textarea>
<button id="button_processing_ta">Обработать</button>
```

Вот обработчик:

```
<?php
  function my_action_javascript() { ?>
    <script>
      document.getElementById( 'button_processing_ta' ).addEventListener( 'click', function() {
        let my_ta = document.getElementById( 'my_ta' );

        // ???
        wpautop( my_ta.value );
      });
    </script>
  <?php }

  add_action( 'admin_print_footer_scripts', 'my_action_javascript', 99 );
?>
```

Спасибо!

Comment: Никак. Ни в wordpress, ни где-либо ещё вы не заставите PHP выполняться в браузере. PHP работает на сервере и генерирует страницу. Javascript который у вас работает в браузере.

Comment: https://wp-kama.ru/id_2018/ajax-v-wordpress.html